# AngularJS - How to take action only on combination of multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on an AngularJS app. This app constructs a complex table of part information with filtering and sorting, etc. The table gets built using two ngRepeat directives. One of them hits a JSON API to get the column headers, and the other gets all the part data for those columns. Based on the part category, the table could have anywhere from 5 to 50 columns, and there could be between 2 and 2000 parts in the category.

After the table is rendered I need to apply a jQuery plugin to enable additional features. My problem is that the plugin initialization is happening too early. I need to only call that init function when the directives have completed all the rendering.

My first step was to create a directive that sets an event I could listen for. Here is what I used:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('myOnLoad', [function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) setTimeout(function(){
            scope.$emit('everythingLoaded', element, attrs);
        }, 1);
    };
}]);
```

I then put the directive on one of my repeaters like this:

```
<th ng-repeat="attribute in ctrl.attributes" attribcol="attribute" class="mps-attribute-cell" my-on-load></th>
```

And then listen for it in my controller:

```
$scope.$on('everythingLoaded', function(scope, element, attrs){
    var containerHeight = jQuery(window).height() - 100;
    jQuery('#mps-table').fixedHeaderTable({
            width: '100%',
            height: containerHeight + 'px',
            fixedColumn: true
     });
});
```

This helped me wait til the attribute columns loaded before the plugin init, but it isn't exactly right yet because the other directive may not be done when this fires. I need to make sure both repeaters are done.

How can I require the *combination* of two different events before the init code fires?

**UPDATE**:

I created a service that looks like this so far:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('featureInit', ['$rootScope',
        function ($rootScope) {
            var featureReady = 0;
            $rootScope.$on('attributesLoaded', function (scope, element, attrs) {
                featureReady++;
                console.log('attributesLoaded so featureReady is now ' + featureReady);
            });
            $rootScope.$on('partsLoaded', function (scope, element, attrs) {
                featureReady++;
                console.log('partsLoaded so featureReady is now ' + featureReady);
            });
            featureInit.init = function() {
                if (featureReady > 1) {
                    console.log('triggers were hit');
                    var containerHeight = jQuery(window).height() - 100;
                    jQuery('#mps-table').fixedHeaderTable({
                        width: '100%',
                        height: containerHeight + 'px',
                        fixedColumn: true
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);
```

I've adjusted the event-emitter directives to produce the correct event when loading is finished and my service correct logs the variable "featureReady". I can see it get logged when it finally gets to "2", at which point I want to run all the code inside the init function.

At this point I am not sure how to get my app to "watch" the featureReady variable so that it will kick off that init function when it hits the right point.

Comment: You could create a service, (since they are singletons) and put a list of things you want to watch inside it, and when all the things you want to watch are completed fire a function.

Comment: If you are using Angular UI Router you can listen for the $viewContentLoadedevent as specified here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#view-load-events

Comment: I'm not using the UI-router. This is a one-page app that is integrated into a CMS. It provides a complex filtering tool for an existing website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it. Here is my custom directive file (chained them into the same file) to handle the event emission:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('partLoadEvent', [function () {
            return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                if (scope.$last)
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        scope.$emit('partsLoaded', element, attrs);
                    }, 1);
            };
        }])
    .directive('attributeLoadEvent', [function () {
            return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                if (scope.$last)
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        scope.$emit('attributesLoaded', element, attrs);
                    }, 1);
            };
        }]);
```

I include the directive on the repeaters like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="part in ctrl.parts" partrow="part" part-load-event></tr>
```

My service looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('featureInit', ['$rootScope',
        function ($rootScope) {
            var featureReady = 0;
            var initThreshold = 2;
            var featureMethods = {
                init: function() {
                    /* do all my post-render stuff */
                }
            };
            $rootScope.$on('attributesLoaded', function (scope, element, attrs) {
                featureReady++;
                if (featureReady >= initThreshold)
                    featureMethods.init();
            });
            $rootScope.$on('partsLoaded', function (scope, element, attrs) {
                featureReady++;
                if (featureReady >= initThreshold)
                    featureMethods.init();
            });
        }]);
```

And finally, include the service into the main controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller("MPSController", ['$http','$sce','_','featureInit', function ($http, $sce, _, featureInit) {
```

Kudos to @Delta for the suggestion to call a function when the threshold was hit. I just had to research a little more for the correct way to get access to the function. I had to attach the function to a variable, rather than "this". (Probably something to do with scope but I'm new to Angular and don't fully get it yet.)

Answer (score 1):

So if you only need to have this class do one thing then i would create a service like this.

```
angular.module('myApp')
        .service('featureService',
        function ()
        {
            var _this = this;
            this.OpenResponses = [];
            this.RemoveResponse = function (responseToRemove)
            {
                var index = this.OpenResponses.indexOf(responseToRemove)
                if (index > -1)
                    this.OpenResponses.splice(index, 1);
                if (this.OpenResponses.length <= 0)
                    this.ResponsesAllFinished();
            };
            this.ResponsesAllFinished = function ()
            {
                //do stuff
            }
        });
```

Then in your directive

```
angular.module('myApp')
        .directive('myOnLoad', ['featureService', function (featureService)
        {
            return function (scope, element, attrs)
            {
                //If doesnt matter what you push in here as long as you remove the same value
                featureService.OpenResponses.push(this);
                if (scope.$last) 
                    featureService.RemoveResponse(this);
            };
        }]);
```

All of this javascript might not be semantically correct, I have been using typescript recently but this should get the general idea across.

Comment: Wouldn't `featureService.OpenResponses.length` end up being reduced to 0 at the end of each directive individually? I have two directives which each emit their own event to signify that a particular type of load has finished. I need to bind my init code to the **combination** of both events.

Comment: if you add both of them to the service, since the service is a singleton it will add each one to the same list.

Comment: I did try it this way but it did not kick off the final function. Am I missing something? Should I $watch the service from the controller?

Comment: you shouldn't have to watch it, when you remove one it will check the count and once it gets to 0 the remove function calls the final function.